# Deep linking for IOS in Xamarin From

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, deep-linking

I'm a xamarin developer who isn't very familiar with the xamarin framework. I have a project where I want to use deep linking for a single payment gateway application ([MobilePay](https://mobilepaydev.github.io/MobilePay-Payments-API/docs/introduction)). I finished the Android version, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the iOS version. Could you please provide me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

For this ,you can check document [Application Indexing and Deep Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking).

On the iOS platform, ensure that your iOS platform project sets the `Entitlements.plist` file as the custom `entitlements` file for signing the bundle.

To use iOS Universal Links:

- Add an Associated Domains entitlement to your app, with the applinks
  key, including all the domains your app will support.
- Add an Apple App Site Association file to your website.
- Add the applinks key to the Apple App Site Association file.

For more information, see [Allowing Apps and Websites to Link to Your Content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content)
on developer.apple.com.

**Note:**

Xamarin.Forms application indexing and deep linking functionality is only available on the iOS and Android platforms, and requires a minimum of iOS 9 and API 23 respectively.